# Interesting Weighted Sum of Binomial Coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

In my research, I've come across the following weighted sum of binomial coefficients:
$$\sum_{i=1}^k i\cdot{2k \choose k+i}.$$
According to Wolfram Alpha, this equals exactly the quantity
$$\frac{1}{2}(k+1){2k \choose k+1}.$$
After trying to prove this, I've come up shorthanded. I have two questions.

1. Is there a direct procedure (or a combinatorial argument) that yields this expression?
2. Is there a general class of weighted sums that could be solved in a similar way?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338764/prove-that-sum-limits-i-1n-2i-binom2nn-i-n-binom2nn

Comment: This is the mean absolute deviation of a Binomial distribution with $p=\frac 12$, first solved by [De Moivre](https://statweb.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/papers/demoivre.pdf). Ivan Loh's solution in the linked problem was the same as that of De Moivre. I doubt there is a simple combinatorial argument. [Brian M. Scott](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/341407/843178) hadn't found one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give a different solution from the two in the linked question.

Now to view it as computing $E|X-k|$ where $X \sim Bin\left(2k,\frac 12\right)$, it's quite natural to do the following:

$$\sum_{i=1}^k i\cdot{2k \choose k+i} = \sum_{i=1}^k (k+i-k) \binom{2k}{k+i} \\
= \sum_{i=1}^k (k+i) \binom{2k}{k+i} - k \sum_{i=1}^k \binom{2k}{k+i}\\
= 2k \sum_{i=1}^k \binom{2k-1}{k+i-1} - k \cdot \frac{2^{2k} - \binom{2k}{k}}{2}\\
= 2k \cdot \frac{2^{2k-1}}{2} - k\cdot \frac{2^{2k} - \binom{2k}{k}}{2}\\ = \frac{k}{2} \binom{2k}{k} = \frac{1}{2}(k+1){2k \choose k+1}. \blacksquare
$$

Note the above quantity  is actually equal to $2^{2k-1}E|X-k|$, not $E|X-k|$.

Comment: Accepted as the solution though Riemann provided a link to the same question with answers, since you provided a new derivation. Also, good insight regarding the interpretation of the sum in your other comment.

Comment: I found another [interpretation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3993007/prove-a-coin-game-is-fair?noredirect=1&lq=1) and it's very close to getting a combinatorial argument. Please stay tuned and see if other members can find a good way of doing that.